# Why is this recursive print function not working in Erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang

Hi newbie here and I am trying to master recursive functions in Erlang. This function looks like it should work, but I cannot understand why it does not. I am trying to create a function that will take `N` and a `string` and will print out to stdout the string the number of times.

My code:

```
-module(print_out_n_times).
-export([print_it/2).

print_it(0, _) ->
     "";

print_it(N, string) ->
     io:fwrite(string),
     print_it(N - 1, string).
```

The error I get is:

```
** exception error: no function clause matching print_it(5, "hello')
```

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables in Erlang start with a capital letter. `string` is an atom, not a variable named "string". When you define a function `print_it(N, string)`, it can be called with any value for the first argument and only the atom `string` as the second. Your code should work if you replace `string` with `String`:

```
print_it(N, String) ->
     io:fwrite(String),
     print_it(N - 1, String).
```

Comment: gosh! missed out on that! Thanks!